Load assets json mock data from Composable Preview
I'm trying to load a local asset json of models to show in my preview (as a replacement for the data remotely requested by the viewmodel), but I came across context issues (I understand I can have no context from a Composable Preview).
I also found PreviewParameterProvider, which looks promising, but seems it's more conceived to 'manually' creating a small list of reusable models, and I'd like to load a relatively large collection.
I guess I could use a parameter provider an directly copypaste my json into a variable but I'm wondering, is there any valid approach to load a models json from my Previews?
